# Is https://div.show/options fraud/malware?

Tags: malware, content-security-policy, fraud

Is https://div.show/options fraud/malware? I saw via https://app.uriports.com that a customer tried to load the page mentioned before and it was blocked thanks to CSP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am working at URIports and checked our stats:

We are processing millions of CSP reports daily and found 99 CSP violations on 14 different domains containing div.show since 2020-07-01. Triggered by multiple versions of Firefox and Chrome on Windows, Linux and MacOS. This is probably caused by a plugin or extension.